# how to send emails to users in data type in PEGA

Tags: pega

i have a data table with employee info namely id, name, company, salary and emailaddress. i want to send emails to employees with salary greater than an amount using an activty. please help me with steps.

I have tries obj browse with select salary>amount-> then loop through embedded pages and then tried to property-set .emailid(property to store emailid from table) = pxresult().emailaddress. But the problem is pxresult(x) contain only salary property because of select condition, I don't know how to get the emailid property from table.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Obj-Browse` method you can add all properties. You can include `emailaddress` property as well.

Check below example

[image]

Now you can do `pxresult().Email` property.